# ELI5: This code is confusing

Tags: php

```
$lastEl = array_values(array_slice($array, -1))[0];
```

So I understand `array_values` and `array_slice` but I'm not sure what the indicator on the end is doing to it.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Since `array_values` returns an array, it's taking only the first element

Comment: **Example #7 Array dereferencing** http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Read about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). It's a long documentation page but it covers most aspects about working with arrays. Bookmark it. Also put a bookmark on the big list of PHP [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you break it down...

```
$lastEl = array_values(array_slice($array, -1))[0];
```

Firstly...

```
array_slice($array, -1)
```

This is taking part of the array the -1 means from the end of the array, so this takes the last element and returns an array.

```
array_values(array_slice($array, -1))
```

This returns the values from the returned array - again as an array.

```
[0]
```

Takes the first element of the resultant array, as so far the result has been an array of 1 element (the last one) it converts the result from an array to the value of the last element of the array.

So an example...

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5];
$lastEl = array_values(array_slice($array, -1))[0];
var_dump($lastEl);
```

will output

```
/home/nigel/workspace2/Test/t2.php:8:
int(5)
```

Comment: So it just gets the last element of the array?

Comment: That is the result - I assume 'lastEl' means 'last Element'

Comment: Thanks guys, I did some more digging, It just takes some of the multidimensionality out of it (`array ( [0] => array())` turns into `array()`

Comment: Also, so far as I can see, this is no different than doing `$lastEl = end($array);`

Comment: There are slight differences, as `end()` will modify some of the internal data of the array, it may have side effects which you don't want.  This method always creates new arrays at each stage and so the original data is not modified.  This may not make any difference to some code.